# Cross-compile Qt for specific arm target from 64bits Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm

I'm currently trying to compile a project and port it to a 32bit target deploying a Linux based system.

My host machine runs x86_64 Debian Stretch and my target is an Atmel SAMA5d2 running a custom Linux.
My cross toolchain is generated from buildroot.

At the moment I'm able to cross compile applications for the target using the buildroot generated toolchain. However, I would like to integrate Qt and build Qt apps for the target.

To be able to build my applications for the targetted platform I need to compile Qt for my target.
To do so I have to tell Qt to use the buildroot toolchain instead of the native one.

From what I found I either have to provide `-device <device> --device-option CROSS_COMPILE=$TOOLCHAIN_PATH` or `-xplatform <mkspec>` to configure Qt with the expected toolchain.

Obviously my target is not in the device list under `qtbase/mkspecs/devices` so I think the best solution is to create a mkspec for my target.

My command should look like this :

```
./configure -xplatform <my_mkspec> -embedded arm -prefix <customQtPath>
```

However I'm kinda lost and I don't know how to do it only from documentation and what I found by googling my problem.
Also do I need to specify the target is 32bit as armv7 is only 32bits?

I would be glad to have some help on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are correct. You can read similar specs and create your own, those are pretty simple. For instance Pi2 is an armv7 device, you can start from [this qmake.conf](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.9/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi2-g%2B%2B/qmake.conf). Then, pass to configure:

```
-device <given_name> -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=<path_and_prefix> -sysroot <your_sysroot>
```

just change paths, tune cflags if needed etc... Then follow build tutorials.

Comment: I thought the device has to be in the list under `qtbase/mkspecs/devices` as it's said in documentation : _italic_The device is selected through the configure tool's -device parameter. The name that follows after this argument must, at least  partially, match one of the subdirectories under devices._italic_
So should I give the create the spec at this location? Also, where could I find documentation about the meaning and use of all those qmake variables?

Comment: Yes, place yours in there. There is a qmake manual but most are not documented. Read the specs for other chips and experiment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and come back to tell you if I succeeded, however it can take a while as I have modifications to do to add Qt in buildroot.